# A line segment inside a square is perpendicular to another line segment that is also inside the square. Find the area in the diagram shown

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

[image]

> $ABCD$ is a square. $|AH|=2$ cm, $|EH|=6$ cm.
>
> $FE||AB$
>
> Find $A(ABEF)$.

There are only few known, so I tried to find some similarities by naming the angles in the right triangles, but I couldn't set up the ratios.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|AB|=:s$, $\>|BE|=:h$. Since $\triangle(AHD)\sim\triangle(EBA)$ we have $${2\over s}={h\over2+6}$$
and therefore
$${\rm area}(ABEF)=hs=16\ .$$